# Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: diophantine-approximation, nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Hi,

I´m looking for Chebyshev´s theorem which says that the inequality $|x(k)-y|<3/k$ has infinitely many solutions, where $x(k)=x_0+k\alpha \pmod 1$, $\alpha$ is an irrational number, and $x_0,y\in S^1$. Does anybody know the exact formulation?

Answer (score 2):

This is a quantitative version of the one-dimensional Kronecker's approximation theorem; see Hardy and Wright's classical text "An introduction to the Theory of Numbers", Theorem 440. You can also check [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem#A_result_in_diophantine_approximation).

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to the [Equidistribution Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) by Weyl